# iOS: core data, number of relationship with Auto ID

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two Entities: Woods and Tree

Woods has a relationship with Tree because a woods can have many trees. 
Ok it's easy.

In my app I know the id of one woods (the auto id: NSManagedObjectID) and I want to know how many tree has my woods.

My code is:

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tree"];
        [req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wood.self == %@", [self app].current_wood_id]];
        [req setResultType:NSCountResultType];
        NSUInteger total = [context countForFetchRequest:req error:&error];
        NSLog(@"total:%d", (int)total);
```

but It doesn't work, why?

Comment: Don't use the object ID, use the object itself in the predicate.

Comment: mmmm can you explain me?

Comment: Don't use the `objectID` of the `Woods`. Use the `Woods` itself. Instantiate a `Woods` from its object ID by using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `objectWithID:` method.

Comment: ok and after? what's the form of predicate to obtain the number of tree of my woods?

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wood == %@", [self app].current_wood]`. As a side note, you're not following proper conventions while naming your variables and methods. I suggest reading this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html Following conventions makes it easier for others to help you with your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop thinking in IDs and instead embrace the object graph. The IDs you are abusing to identify objects are not there for this purpose (but for identifying object across threads).

The relationship in a predicate is written just like an attribute:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wood = %@", aWoodInstance];
```

In you specific case, you do not need a fetch request. Just write:

```
wood.trees.count
```

It could not be easier! See how powerful the object graph is?